# C++, Armadillo: Procedure Entry Point H5Ovisit Could not be Located in libarmadillo.dll

Tags: c++, mingw, hdf5, armadillo, msys2

I'm using MSYS2 with MinGW64. I insalled the `Armadillo` and `HDF5` libraries by using the command `pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-hdf5 mingw-w64-x86_64-armadillo`

I tried to run this offical demo program:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <armadillo>

using namespace std;
using namespace arma;

int main()
{
  mat A = randu<mat>(4,5);
  mat B = randu<mat>(4,5);
  
  cout << A*B.t() << endl;
  
  return 0;
}
```

I compiled it with the command `g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp -o main -O3 -static-libstdc++ -larmadillo`

The compilation succeeded, but when I ran `main.exe`, it gave me this error message:
`The procedure entry point H5Ovisit could not be located in the DLL D:\MSYS2\mingw64\bin\libarmadillo.dll`

I used `Dependency Walker` to analyze `main.exe` and found these:

1. `libhdf5-0.dll` is a dependency of `libarmadillo.dll`. `H5Ovisit` is in `libhdf5-0.dll`'s parent import function list, but missing from its export function list. (I think this is the core of the problem)
2. These functions do exist in `libhdf5-0.dll`'s export function list: `H5Ovisit1`, `H5Ovisit2`, `H5Ovisit3`, `H5Ovisit_by_name1`, `H5Ovisit_by_name2`, `H5Ovisit_by_name3`
3. In `D:\MSYS2\mingw64\include\armadillo_bits\def_hdf5.hpp`, I found this: `#define arma_H5Ovisit H5Ovisit`

Could anyone help me future to solve my problem please?

Comment: try compiling like this: `g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp -o main -DARMA_DONT_USE_WRAPPER -DARMA_DONT_USE_HDF5 -O3 -static-libstdc++ -lopenblas`. This will avoid using the run-time wrapper library (libarmadillo) and the HDF5 library. This assumes you have OpenBLAS installed.  If not, change `-lopenblas` to `-lblas -llapack`

Comment: @hbrerkere: It works! Thanks a lot. Your commet sould be a proper answer.